# Migrating Database from MySQL Workbench to SharePoint List for Python Flask Application

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, python, sql-query

We are new to this site and request your kind support in solving our query.

We have a created python flask based web application wherein we have used MySQL WorkBench as a database.

Now, we have been requested to change the database from MySQL to SharePoint List.

We would like to know if we can connect to SharePoint List with Python code. If yes, how to change the code base to the minimum with regards to MySQL queries as we were informed that SharePoint List supports MsSQL queries.

Sincerely,
Irfan M.